# Asp.net Login Session Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

in the login page:

```
Session("FirstName") = txtUserName.Text
Response.Redirect("CusRecords.aspx")
```

in the second page:

```
lbl1.Text = Session("FirstName").ToString
```

I used that code an I get this error :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
that error refers to lbl1.Text = Session("FirstName").ToString
```

this is the full code of login page:

```
Public Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public s As String
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Session.Clear()
    Session.Abandon()
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RegconnectionString").ConnectionString)
    con.Open()
    Dim userCount As Int32 = GetUserCount(txtUserName.Text)
    Dim paasCount As Int32 = GetPassCount(TxtPassword.Text)


    If userCount > 0 And paasCount > 0 Then
        Session("FirstName") = txtUserName.Text
    Else
        lblErr.Visible = True
    End If
    Response.Redirect("CusRecords.aspx")
End Sub



' Method to check existence 
Public Shared Function GetUserCount(ByVal userName As String) As Int32
    Const sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Registration where username = @UserName"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RegconnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName)
            con.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    reader.Read()
                    Dim count As Int32 = reader.GetInt32(0)
                    Return count
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function



Public Shared Function GetPassCount(ByVal password As String) As Int32
    Const sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Registration where password = @Password"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RegconnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password)
            con.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    reader.Read()
                    Dim count As Int32 = reader.GetInt32(0)
                    Return count
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function





Protected Sub txtUserName_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles txtUserName.TextChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

Other Page:

```
Public Class CusRecords
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Session("FirstName") IsNot Nothing Then
        lbl1.Text = DirectCast(Session("FirstName"), String)
    Else
        lbl1.Text = "It is empty"
    End If


End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I would suggest putting a break point on the Session("FirstName") = txtUserName.Text and put a watchon the Session so you can see what it is being set to.

Comment: when I debugged it, it`d not change, it`ll stay null
Session("FirstName") = txtUserName.Text >> is not working

Comment: Can you post the entire page code please, you may be loosing the username.text content during the login phase so you can't set the Session variable.

Comment: I fixed it by deleting Session.Abandon()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure the session isn't null

```
If Session("FirstName") IsNot Nothing Then
    lbl1.Text = DirectCast(Session("FirstName"), String)
End If
```

If the error continues, make sure that lbl1 isn't null

Also, notice this line:

```
If userCount > 0 And paasCount > 0 Then
    Session("FirstName") = txtUserName.Text
Else
    lblErr.Visible = True
End If
Response.Redirect("CusRecords.aspx")
```

So ***you're always redirecting*** even if you didn't set the Session("FirstName") variable - this might be why it's null

**Edit:**
Final problem is calling the Session.Clear() and Session.Abandon() in the Page_Load

Comment: The Session is null or the lbl1?

Comment: session is not filled by this line :
Session("FirstName") = txtUserName.Text

Comment: Remove the Session.Clear() and Session.Abandon() from the Page_Load... Did it help? - Edit: Also notice my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by deleting this line

```
Session.Abandon()
```

Comment: @Rory, the **OP** is saying that he fixed his own problem by removing that line.   So not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it does actually provide an answer, and it's the author.

Comment: Sorry, so it did. That was a comment auto-generated by the review tool as this answer was flagged as low quality due to length and content. I missed the fact it was the OP answering his own question.

Answer (score 0):

try this   lbl1.Text = Session("FirstName") do not type ToString().